# Remove URL parameter in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this link:

```
http://www.afif.qa/projects/?category=wells
```

I want to use it like this:

```
http://www.afif.qa/projects/wells
```

I already used .htaccess in the WordPress main folder

This is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ projects.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

but WordPress redirect me to the 404 page, i already used this code with no-WordPress website and it worked,

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]*)$ /projects/?category=$1 [L]
```

This should leave you with the following URL: `http://www.afif.qa/projects/wells`. Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.